# Android WearOS ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is being ignored

Tags: android, android-permissions, wear-os, android-doze

On Android WearOS with SDK 28 I am trying to disable doze mode.  From my understanding, the following code will disable doze mode:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName());
if(!isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
}
```

In my manifest I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Later in my activity I have added the following code to test if battery optimizations have been disabled (what I understand doze mode to be)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName());
    if(isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations){
        // Ignoring battery optimization
        Log.e(logTAG, "WORKED");
    }else{
        // Not ignoring battery optimization
        Log.e(logTAG, "NOPE");
    }
}
```

What I get in the log is "NOPE".  Moreover, doze mode is also not being disabled (which is what I would expect with NOPE being printed).  Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to disable doze mode on WearOS?

Comment: Which device are you testing on?

Comment: Do you get the system settings where the user can add you app to the allow list? https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: No, there is no battery optimization sub menu.

Comment: I assume it is not supported on this device, or generally on Wear OS 2.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

갤럭시 워치5 에서도 ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS intent action이 무시됩니다

ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS intent action is ignored in Galaxy Watch 5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).